# Correlation to Covariance Matrix

Tags: matrix

I am looking to use the CopulaDistribution fucntion, with a "MultiNormal" kernal. However, for the input, O require a covariance matrix. However, I only have a  correlation matrix. Is there a way to convert one to the other?

Answer (score 4):

You also need `StandardDeviation` to get the covariance matrix from the correlation matrix:

```
corToCov[mat_, sd_] := Transpose[sd Transpose[sd mat]]
```

Example:

```
data = RandomReal[5, {10, 5}];
cormat = Correlation[data];
covmat = Covariance[data];
sd = StandardDeviation[data];
covmat ==  corToCov[cormat, sd]
(* True *)
```

To get the correlation matrix from a covariance matrix ([Correlation >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Correlation.html)):

```
covToCor[cov_, sd_] := Transpose[Transpose[cov/sd]/sd];
cormat == covToCor[covmat, sd]
(* True *)
```

Comment: What if I do not have the data. All I have is correlation matrix.

Comment: @Jim, i don't know how one can recover the covariance matrix from a correlation matrix without knowing the standard deviation.